# Can I change property of element in DataTemplate, and how?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, resources, datatemplate

Can I change property of element in DataTemplate ?
For example:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>       
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LawItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Name}" 
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I want to change TextBlock FontSize, but How I can get access to TextBock in DataTemplate?

Option to create Load Event and get an element by sender does not fit, because the changes visually noticeable to the user.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to change it on runtime? "because the changes visually noticeable to the user" Can you explain more?

Comment: When information is loaded, the FontSize/Color is the standard at first, and after a half-second change. It is visually noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change something in a `DataTemplate` just bind it to a property on your data and change that instead. Messing with the controls should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get the root element of `ListBox` item

```
ListBoxItem item = listbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListBoxItem;
```

Then search `TextBlock` in elements tree with several calls to `.Children()` or give a `Name` to `TextBlock` and search by name

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is what you mean, but you can use `Trigger`s.

Like so:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LawItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NameHolder"
                Text="{Binding Name}" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProp}" Value="SomeValue">
                    <Setter TargetName="NameHolder" Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Of course, you can use `RelativeSource` in the binding of the trigger if you need to listen to property changes of a visual ancestor.